# Colors in ExclusionsStyle

Tags: plotting

I have the following Plot:

[image]

Apparently MMA uses `ColorData[1,1]` for the edges in all graphs. I already tried adding

```
ExclusionsStyle -> {ColorData[1, 1], ColorData[1, 2], ColorData[1, 3]}
```

but that doesn't help; it only uses the first listed color. Adding `Directive' only uses the *last* listed color:

```
ExclusionsStyle -> Directive[{ColorData[1, 1], ColorData[1, 2], Red}]]
```

Any idea how I can Plot the edges in the same colors as the graphs?

**edit**
The code, upon request:

```
sqw[x_, f_] := SquareWave[x f]/3;  
Plot[{sqw[x, 1] + 2.5, sqw[x, 0.95] + 1.5, -3 sqw[x, 1] sqw[x, 0.95] + 0.5}, {x, -1, 4},  
Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2]},  
ExclusionsStyle -> {ColorData[1, 1], ColorData[1, 2], ColorData[1, 3]}]
```

Comment: You may post the code you are using for generating those plots ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps

```
sqw[x_, f_] := SquareWave[x f]/3;
Plot[{sqw[x, 1] + 2.5, sqw[x, 0.95] + 1.5, -3 sqw[x, 1] sqw[x, 0.95] + 0.5}, {x, -1, 4}, 
         Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> {AbsoluteThickness[2]}, Exclusions -> False]
```

[image]

**Edit**

But you may find troubles if you need to specify a different Style for the exclusions in each function. For example, the following does not work as expected:

```
Plot[{2 + Floor[x], Floor[x]}, {x, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}, 
 Exclusions -> True,  ExclusionsStyle -> {{Yellow, Green}, {White, Black}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Perhaps?? I'd say for sure! :-) Thanks a bunch!

Comment: For those wondering what happened to the first spikes on the 3th function: I cleaned up the functions a bit (rounded numbers and such) :-)

Comment: The obvious question for the `Floor` addition is: is there a fix? (probably not an easy one, otherwise you would probably have added it)

Comment: @stevenvh Obviously not :)